# How to use mod_rewrite with multiple user_ids and multiple templates

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite

I have a membership program written with PHP and using mysql where users input their product information to be displayed on public webpages with URLs that look like this:

```
http://domain.com/folder/page.php?id=62&template=7
```

I want to use mod_rewrite to convert the pages to:

```
http://domain.com/folder/62/7
```

The `id` could be any number from 1 through 10,000, and the `template` could be any number from 1-100. How would the mod_rewrite rule or condition look? And if I needed to write PHP code to include with the mod_rewrite rule to handle multiple `id`s and multiple `template`s, what code would accompany the mod_rewrite?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple ids? Do you mean in the same URL so you would have http://domain.com/folder/62/7/.../4/3/5 ??

Comment: Yes, id could be any number, and template could be any number.

Comment: If there could be any number of url variables the code in the answer given will not work. That only works for 2 url variables. Is that what you want?

Comment: No! I guess that's why it doesn't work. I need the mod_rewrite to work with `id=` any number between 1-10000, and `template=` any number between 1-100. New members will be signing up, so new numbers will be added daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+) page.php?id=$1&template=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @ Pierpaolo thannks, but I'm getting a 404

Comment: Hmmm, still getting 404. Is it possible my host does not have mod_rewrite enabled on Apache? Is there some way I can tell?

Comment: If it isn't installed you get a Server Error, not a 404. Check: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @ Pierpaolo could the possible problem be that I'm hosting 3 domains on the same IP, and the mod_rewrite code you gave is not taking that into consideration? My directory path is `/home/user/public_html/domain.com` where domain.com is one of 3 domains. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @ Pierpaolo after much more research, I found that dropping `RewriteBase /` and `folder/` from your mod_rewrite code, it worked. I used the rest of your code: `Rewrite ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) page.php?id=$1&template=$2 [L]` and it works. Another solution that works is `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1&template=$2 [L]`